# Can SlopeOne Algo be used for this problem?

Tags: algorithm, collaborative-filtering

I need to implement collaborative filtering techniques to gives users similar functionality which Amazon gives when you an individual item that is,"People who visited this also visited these". I have made initial attempts to study different types of CF like item-item or user-item. I am having difficulty to figure out which one should I use for the mentioned purpose. Can Slope One Algo be used for this purpose if yes then how could it be? I am using PHP/MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Can it be used? yes. It operates on the same inputs and delivers the same output. Whether it's the best solution entirely depends on your problem domain. [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) has implementations of all of these, so you could test-drive each approach.